# Can children post images of themselves that are not sexually explicit but provocative

Tags: pornography, child-porn

I know child pornography is illegal to make and distribute, and thus illegal for a child to post sexually explicit imagery of themselves. However, is it legal for them to simply post suggestive images of themselves with no explicitly shown sexual content?

Comment: In other words...  The laws regarding such things vary wildly in different jurisdictions.  Please update your posting with the location you are talking bout.

Comment: Also, please define "suggestive."

Comment: Are you asking what the law says on the topic in... Thailand, Somalia, The UK, Iran, The Russian Federation, on Thahiti, or maybe In the Shi'ar Empire?

Comment: Perhaps we should say: Please define “sexually explicit” (especially given [Reed Sexton’s answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/79469/35266)).

Answer (score 2):

For the United States (you didn't mention a country).

By definition, content that is not "sexually explicit" does not constitute child pornography and is not illegal. However, sexually explicit content “is not limited to nude exhibitions or exhibitions in which the outlines
of those areas were discernible through clothing.” (18 U.S.C. § 2252). In United States v. Knox (510 US 375), the conviction of a man for possessing “videotapes that focus on the genitalia and pubic area of minor females... even though these body parts are covered by [opaque] clothing” was upheld.